# Using the result of grep to sort files

Tags: sorting, awk, sed, grep

I need to sort a file based on the results of grep. Example:

```
cat cuts.txt | grep -P '(?<=[+]).*(?=[+])'
text +124+ text
text +034+ text
text +334+ text
```

How do I sort lines in crescent order based on what grep found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Considering that you need to sort by 2nd field's increasing values. Since OP mentioned `+digits+` values could be present anywhere in line hence coming with this Generic solution here.

```
grep -P '(?<=[+]).*(?=[+])' Input_file |
awk '
  match($0,/\+[0-9]+\+/){
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),$0
  }
'  | sort -k1.2 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Output will be as follows.

```
text +034+ text
text +124+ text
text +334+ text
```

***Logical explanation:*** After passing `grep` command's output to `awk` command using regex in `awk` command to find `+digits+` values in lines and printing 1st matched values then whole line, by doing this it will be easy for `sort` to why because we always get to sort now on 1st field. Once we do sorting on first field then use cut to get everything from 2nd field onwards, why because 1st field is an extra added field by `awk` command to make `sort` easier and not needed in actual output.

Also we need NOT to use a separate `cat` command to this one, we could directly read Input_file by `grep` command.

Comment: That would work, but in my specific case the numbers inside + + will sometimes be on a different position.

Comment: @CARMINATISOUND, you would have mentioned that in your question, answers will be always provided as per question's samples only, let me fix it now.

Comment: @CARMINATISOUND, Could you please try my edited solution now and let me know then how it goes? Also we need not to use `cat` command here, just directly read Input_file(file which has values to be read) to `grep` command.

Comment: Very good! Thank you. I added -n option to sort and it worked as intended.